# tutorial of eventKit

Tags: ios4

can i find tutorial of eventKit anywhere?
Or can anybody suggest me how to kickstart my eventKit programming

Answer (score 1):

Just for people who is looking the same subject. Check the SimpleEKDemo Example from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

YES, you can refer to the below link and get a tutorial on creating event into a calendar. This is a very nice and precise tutorial.

http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-use-event-kit-ui-apple-ios-4-sdk-395865/

Hope this helps you.